# Differences between Parallel.ForEach and await ForEachAsync

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Is there any reason to choose Parallel.ForEach instead of await ForEachAsync in any situation (or vice-versa)? or they are virtually the same?

```
await collection.ForEachAsync( m => { m.DoSomething(); } );
```

VS

```
Parallel.ForEach( collection, m => { m.DoSomething(); } );
```

Comment: for some reason someone down vote this question, I up voted it because it is a very valid question

Comment: Which `ForEachAsync` are you talking about? There are a lot of different implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not 'virtually the same' at all.

When you use functions from the [Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel?view=netframework-4.7.2) class such as `Parallel.ForEach()` you are invoking some action, in which that action is broken up into multiple smaller actions, each carried out on different threads (aka multi-threaded).

`ForEachAsync` on the other hand is **not** necessarily multi-threaded. It is asynchronous and asynchronous operations are not multi-threaded ones (well they can be, but don't have to be, that depends on the implementation).

I strongly suggest reading the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680985/what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-programming-and-multithreading) which goes into far more detail on the topic.

As for you question of

> Is there any reason to choose Parallel.ForEach instead of await ForEachAsync in any situation

The answer is most definitely that there are reasons to do so, but in order to determine what kind of scenarios you would use one or the other, you have to understand them both.

Here's a simple example:

You have a collection of objects and you want to iterate over them and perform some kind of action. Do you care about the order in which those actions occur? If so do not use `Parallel.ForEach()` as there is no guarantee of the order in which they are invoked (due to its multi-threaded nature).

EDIT:

In your example, it all depends on how many items are in `collection` and how process-heavy `DoSomething()` is.

The reason for that is because `Parallel.ForEach()` is **not free**. There are trade-offs to be made. Setting up a multi-threaded environment takes time and if `collection` is small and/or `DoSomething()` doesn't take *too* long, then the time spent setting up those threads would be better (and usually faster) spent with a single-threaded async operation.

On the other hand, if `collection` is large and/or `DoSomething()` is a process-heavy task then `Parallel.ForEach()` will most definitely be the most performant option.

Comment: I've added an example. Can I assume then that performance wise there is no benefit in using the await async in that scenario? (since it doesn't create different threads to be run in parallel, the actual code is all done in one processor)

Comment: Parallelism and multithreading are not the same thing at all.  You can perform asynchronous operations in parallel without using multiple threads, for example.  There are lots of ways of doing things in parallel.  Using multiple threads is just one of them.

Comment: Yes.  It's not what you said at all. You said, "When you use parallelism you are invoking some action [...] each carried out on different threads (aka multi-threaded)." which states that parallelism is multithreading, you say, "[...]do not use parallelism as there is no guarantee of the order in which they are invoked (due to its multi-threaded nature)" again, stating that parallelism is synonyms with multithreading. "Instead an asynchronous operation might be useful." Operations being asynchronous doesn't mean they're executed sequentially (they may or may not be, depending on the specifics).

Comment: "The reason for that is because parallelism is not free. There are trade-offs to be made. Setting up a multi-threaded environment takes time" Again, parallelism is not the same as multithreading.  You can parallelize things without using multiple threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190782/discussion-between-darren-ruane-and-servy).

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23833635/1159478) explains not only the difference between asynchronous and multithreading, but also how "parallelism" relates to both of them, for any readers who were confused by this post.

Answer (score 5):

it is all depend on the threads
let's say you have the following class

```
public class person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is your main Class

```
List<person> persons = new List<person>()
            {
                new person{ ID = 1,Name="Ali"}
                ,new person{ ID = 2,Name="Gorge"}
                ,new person{ ID = 3,Name="Alex"}
                ,new person{ ID = 4,Name="Liz"}
                ,new person{ ID = 5,Name="Scott"}
                ,new person{ ID = 6,Name="Abby"}
                ,new person{ ID = 7,Name="Sarah"}
            };

            Parallel.ForEach(persons, (p) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Id : {p.ID} ,Name : {p.Name}");
            });
```

When you run this code the list items will be splits over diff threads and the code won't be running in order as you see in the following output I get the print in diff order than my original List 
[image]

and here I am running the same code one more time, but I get diff results

[image]

The reason for that because of the threads, the compiler divide to number of threads and every list run the items assigned to it 
the following pic show the diff threads

[image]

but when you run the following code

```
List<person> persons = new List<person>()
            {
                new person{ ID = 1,Name="Ali"}
                ,new person{ ID = 2,Name="Gorge"}
                ,new person{ ID = 3,Name="Alex"}
                ,new person{ ID = 4,Name="Liz"}
                ,new person{ ID = 5,Name="Scott"}
                ,new person{ ID = 6,Name="Abby"}
                ,new person{ ID = 7,Name="Sarah"}
            };

            await persons.ForEachAsync(async p => Console.WriteLine($"Id : {p.ID} ,Name : {p.Name}"));
```

you only get one thread as showing here

[image]

plus the data print **will always be running in the same order** of your list

I hope this answer explains the difference !

Comment: I downvoted because 1. It just seems to be incorrect. `ForEachAsync()` does create a lot of threads on my machine. It also doesn't "run in the same order"; 2. `persons.ForEachAsync()` doesn't seem to exist as direct/extension method, it's `Parallel.ForEachAsync(person, ...)`

Comment: @J.P. the answer was provided in Mar 2019, I don't remember which .Net/ .Net core version
But the screenshots from a running example 
Keep in mind there are always breaking changes this could be one of them, If the question has the same function then this was a valid during the time of the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any reason to choose Parallel.ForEach instead of await ForEachAsync in any situation (or vice-versa)?

`Parallel.ForEach` is for synchronous code. Its delegate must be synchronous, and it is invoked synchronously.

`ForEachAsync` is not a standard algorithm. There are several different implementations, but generally they attempt to do a mixture of asynchrony and parallelism. They have to give up some of the self-balancing aspects of `Parallel.ForEach`. The vast majority of code does not need `ForEachAsync`; most code is *either* asynchronous *or* parallel.